# Lightning Component Field Binding conditional expression

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic-binding, databinding

In a component, initially i was binding a case picklist field value as an attribute. But now, i have requirement to bind it to a different field based on a boolean flag.

Original Code snippet (inside my component) which works fine

```
<c:CstmComp value={v.case.Field1__c}/>
```

CstmComp is another component embedded inside my component. It has a string attribute called value. We bind a picklist field Field1__c to it. CstmComp shows bunch of dropdown values which gets saved to Field1__c

Now i have to make it conditionally bind to Field1__c or Field2__c based on a boolean flag. I am trying following, but doesn't seem to work. Fields come out blank.

```
<aura:attribute name="flag" type="boolean" default="false"/> 
<!--- flag gets read from a custom setting in doInit controller method -->
 <c:CstmComp  value={!v.flag?v.Case.Field1__c:v.Case.Field2__c}/>
```

What i expect is that when flag is true, the dropdown values displayed by CstmComp gets saved to Field1__c, and when it is false, it gets saved to Field2__c

Flag's value is getting set to true or false correctly, i have checked that. Dont know why none of the field gets bound to my CstmComp. Something wrong with the binding expression. Can someone help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way do to this would be to use aura:if:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.flag}">
  <c:CstmComp  value="{!v.Case.Field1__c}"/>
  <aura:set attribute="else">
    <c:CstmComp  value="{!v.Case.Field2__c}"/>
  </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

You could probably also use SecureComponent#getReference and wire it up in your controller, but I think this method is probably easier to read.